# Validating JWT with modulus and exponent vs public key

Tags: java, oauth, keycloak, okta

I'm attempting to write some portable code to validate JWT's in Java.  I'm specifically integrating with Okta and Keycloak.  I'm struggling to understand the parameters returned for the JWKS endpoint.

For Keycloak, I get a key something like:

```
{
  "kid": "H5NDPL2NT2M5_5EOqt91vfPIo13r455Hlu2GYscOBmA",
  "kty": "RSA",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "use": "sig",
  "n": "w7vsnNpTZaOMp3zxKCiEivoIaY...",
  "e": "AQAB",
  "x5c": [
    "MIIClTCCAX0CBgGF9UsKo..."
  ],
  "x5t": "tGzP61KCiwgg-NYlnDIHLB9ZoMw",
  "x5t#S256": "JfHngo5l9TUcI9Up7gTAksLVOs1ivcMcwu-WY01gBDM"
},
```

For Okta, I get:

```
{
  "kty": "RSA",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "u4G-oEtqld6rzHgW7aGPWpcyGABi9JqWAIA7s6_tGm0",
  "use": "sig",
  "e": "AQAB",
  "n": "k9XEKD99izmvBUtnkaGC..."
},
```

My rather limited understanding was that I could generate the public key from the "e" (exponent) and "n" (modulus) fields.  To me it seemed that Keycloak was sending the same data twice by including `x5c[0]`.  But that is apparently not the case.  On the Keycloak side, using code like:

```
// modulusString is "n", exponentString is "e"
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(modulusString));
BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(exponentString));
RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);
```

results in a `PublicKey` that can't be used to validate a token with the Auth0 JWTVerifier:

```
JWTVerifier jwtVerifier = new JWTVerifier(publicKey);

try {
    jwtVerifier.verify(token);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // token is not valid
}
```

Yet on Keycloak if I *do* use `x5c[0]` and convert it with:

```
byte[] decodedCert = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64CertWithoutDelimiters);
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedCert);
publicKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

and the same JWTVerifier code the token from Keycloak validates fine.  So obviously the `generatePublic` isn't doing the same thing.  A print of the Base64 values confirms this.

Looking at the [Okta key resolver code](https://github.com/okta/okta-jwt-verifier-java/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/com/okta/jwt/impl/jjwt/RemoteJwkSigningKeyResolver.java) seems to show pretty much the same thing I'm doing but the Keycloak one doesn't work.  For reference, this is Keycloak 20.0.3.

Can you point me in the correct direction on this?  My Google-fu is at it's end and I still don't have an answer.  Thanks for any help.

***EDIT***

The code that generates the `PublicKey` from the modulus/exponent *was* correct.  It turns out I was incorrectly using the `x5c[0]` key from Keycloak.  Generating the PublicKey with the modulus/exponent now means that I can validate Keycloak and Okta in the same way.  Thanks to @PhilippGrigoryev for pushing me to understand why I was doing things with an ancient library ('cause I'm stuck with an ancient programming environment) and making me look deeper into the problem.

Additionally, I was able to use the code in the [Auth0 JWKS library](https://github.com/auth0/jwks-rsa-java) to direct me in the right place.  My environment prevents me from actually using a modern library but that's a different issue.

Comment: I was not able to find the constructor for `JWTVerifier` which you used. Where does it come from?

Comment: That was the correct question @PhilippGrigoryev - I'm using an ancient (2016, v2.2.2) version of the Auth0 libraries due to an equally prehistoric FinTech programming environment.  I eventually found my answer and, as is common with me, I was making it far too hard.  Thanks for pushing me in the right direction.  I'll update the post with my findings.

Comment: Yay :) glad I could help somehow!